# Why did all the dragons leave Hiccup's team right after Grimmel kidnapped Toothless & the Light Fury?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In *How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World* (2019), I didn't understand the scene where all the dragons left Hiccup's team right after Grimmel kidnapped Toothless & the Light Fury. Why did they do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the events of the second movie, Toothless is the alpha dragon - all other dragons will follow his will.

Grimmel captured Toothless and the Light Fury, using her as leverage to force Toothless to do his own bidding, which was basically to command the dragons to leave the Berkians.